# Use CDO Send Emails in Excel VBA Not Working

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am trying to send email within Excel VBA. Based on my research on Internet, I enabled `Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library` and composed my VBA codes as below:

```
Sub SendCDOMail()
    Dim objCDOMsg As Object

    Set objCDOMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    'CDO Configuration
    With objCDOMsg.Configuration.Fields
        '
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        'Server port (typically 25, 587)
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587
        'SMTP server IP or Name
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
        'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        'SMTP Account User ID
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "xxx@bbbb.com"
        'SMTP Account Password
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "xxxxxxx"
        'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
        .Update
    End With

    'CDO Message
    objCDOMsg.Subject = "TEST Subject"
    objCDOMsg.From = "xx@xx.com"
    objCDOMsg.To = "xx@xx.com"
    objCDOMsg.TextBody = "TEST Body"

    objCDOMsg.Send

End Sub
```

However, I received the error saying:

```
The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: 530.5.7.57 SMTP;
Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
```

I also tried the same configurations using PowerShell and it worked (smtpserver, username, password, server port...).
I don't know where it might go wrong.

Comment: Are you using exactly the same values in Powershell for .From and sendusername? It kind of sounds like the server isn't recognizing the From address - your example has different usernames/From values.

Comment: @dbmitch username and from values are different in my case; username is LANID and from is real email address. And it works in PowerShell.

Comment: Weird. This works fine with GMail.

Comment: But I am having all kinds of issues getting it to work with hotmail.

Comment: @Rodger Gmail seems to be more friendly; it just didn't work for office365

Comment: Did the solution below take care of it with outlook365?

Comment: @Rodger I tried to follow the instructions; however, Microsoft updated the layout of the portal so I can't find those modules specified in the instructions. I need to do some more research.

Comment: Ah well nuts. Once you find it can you be sure to answer your own question with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt210446(v=exchg.150).aspx - note that this is in the Office365 section for "How to set up a multifunction device or application to send email using Office 365,", so there may be other things in there for you too.

This indicates that you are connecting to the SMTP client submission endpoint (smtp.office365.com), which can't be used for direct send. For direct send, **use the MX endpoint for your Office 365 tenant, which ends with "mail.protection.outlook.com."** You can find your MX endpoint by following the steps in [Full configuration instructions for direct send.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c0012a9-7e71-40cd-a516-1b26117bf491%28v=exchg.150%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#DirectSendConfig)