# Including code for library reference to sending an email via excel

Tags: excel, vba, reference

For work we have excel files where we create reports that are approved electronically and saved as a PDF via excel module coding.  I have set-up a command button to send an email to the clients when reports have been approved so they know when to get on and look at new ones.  However, I need a way to code excel to include the appropriate references on the project manager's computer when they go to click the "SendEmail" command button so they do not have to do it manually each time they are in a different project excel.

Here is the coding I have for sending an email-- 
**is there a way to include coding for excel to select the references I need without having to manually select them each time on each computer? (and without having to include another separate command button)**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS43J.png)

Comment: Please paste your code in the question as a code snippet, not as an image.

Comment: The short answer is: use late-binding.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use early binding - here is an example of creating an email from Excel without any references:

```
Sub LateBindingEmailExample()

    Dim mail As Object, msg As Object

    Set mail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set msg = mail.createitem(0)

    With msg
        .To = "exampleemail@exampledomain.com"
        .Subject = "Here is the subject"
        .htmlBody = "Here is the body"
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With

    Set msg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This coding works, but doesn't allow for the email to sent via the gmail account in the original coding :/ is there a way to specify to be sent via gmail with this coding without having to change the references used?

Comment: @S.Jarrett You need to just use late-binding to create your CDO object instead - `CreateObject("CDO.Message")` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032951/use-cdo-send-emails-in-excel-vba-not-working) for a better example.

Comment: I have been trying that all morning and am getting an "Automation error" each time I try to run the coding

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a "VBA Add-in for Microsoft Excel".
Pasting here the definition from [CPearson website](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CreateAddIn.aspx):

> An XLA Add-In is a certain type of workbook that provides custom functions and/or tools that extend the basic functionality of Excel. An Add-In may contain User Defined Functions that provide calculation functions specific to your own area of interest or business, functions that extend beyond the normal calculation capability of Excel. An Add-In can also provide tools to manipulate the data in a workbook. Indeed, an Add-In can be written to do nearly anything you want. If it can be done manually, it can be automated with an XLA Add-In.

The high level reasoning is the following:

- You put the "send an email" code you have in your workbook in a new workbook, in which you add all the necessary references and generic code
- Then, you save your workbook as an Add-in instead of a simple Macro-activated Workbook (extension `.xlam`).
- You ask your user to install the add-in **once** in their Microsoft Excel: since then, they will be able to use that functionality on any workbook they open, without explicitly need to write code in it.

There's a ton of guides on the Internet about how to make cool add-ins, I suggest you the following:

- Very basic add-in with Excel ribbon button (useful if you want them to email the `ActiveWorkbook` as PDF file without that workbook actually have any code in it): [find it here](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-add-in/).
- More complete list of links about how to create an add-in for Excel: [find it here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CreateAddIn.aspx).

Please note you can write Excel add-ins in `VBA`, though you might use languages as `C#` (or `VB.NET`, though I prefer the first one) to have many more functionalities and flexibility.
If you just need to email the workbook and already have a working code for that in VBA, then go on with VBA add-in. But I suggest you don't exclude `C#` cause it's extremely more powerful.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  This is a good suggestion, however the men I work with will consider this too much hassle and not want to take the extra steps, which is why I need to create coding that does everything automatically and only requires them to press the button to send the email after report approval.

Comment: @S.Jarrett in fact, when you do something like this they will still have to click a single button. The difference is that instead of clicking the button on the spreadsheet, they click it on their ribbon and so they can send by email any sheet without necessarily having the code in it.

Comment: I do not need to email any sheets from the excel. I just need to send a pre-generated email stating "New reports have been approved and are available via your client access."

Comment: @S.Jarrett same principle, an Add-In is just an easier way to distribute code. When you distribute it inside an Excel workbook, they need to open _that specific_ Excel workbook and run _that specific button_. When your code is not dependent on any workbook, then an add-in allows you to run _that specific code_ by _any Excel workbook_ (even if they are working on something else). But I understand it'd be easier for you to just code it into a static workbook :)

Comment: I found a code that works, thank you for your time and input!